# Load Stressing Web applications deployed in openstack instances under an autoscaling group

Tags: servlets, jmeter, load-balancing, openstack, autoscaling

I am working testing the auto-scaling feature of OpenStack. In my test set-up, java servlet applications are deployed in tomcat web servers behind a HAproxy load balancer. I aim at stressing testing the application, to see how it scales and the response time using JMeter as the stress tester. However the I observe that HAProxy (or something else) terminates the connection immediately the onComplete signal is sent by one of the member instances. Consequently, the subsequent responses from the remaining servers are reported as failures (timeouts). I have configured the HAProxy server to use a round-robin algorithm with sticky sessions. See attached JMeter results tree , I am not sure of the next step to undertake. The web applications are asyncronous hence my expectation was that the client (HAProxy in this case) should wait until the last thread is submitted before sending the response.

Is there be some issues with my approach or some set up flaws ? 
[image]

Comment: Have you added appropriate timer between the requests?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam I am ramping up 30 secs. I tried also with constant timer using 2 mins , but there was no feasible difference.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear enough. What's the nature of your request? What is onComplete and what it has with load balancer? Basically, what you expect to be happening there?

Comment: Have added Cache and Cookie manager to your test plan?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam yes, I added the cookie manager, but not cache. Will add now that you mentioned. I am completely new to JMeter and load-testing hence i am still trying to understand all the parameters/ configuration.

Comment: @Yuri, sorry for some of the terms which might be unclear. 'onComplete' is a method for handling Asynchronous servlets, it signifies that all threads have been responded to. The web application has a long-running task ....security scanning of other web applications hence it requires time to process the requests that it receives from the clients. The load balancer receives requests and distributes to the back end web servers.